# Ruby on Rails: MySql Gem does not work: uninitialized constant Mysql::Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, osx-lion

I have the following installed:
Mac Os 10.7.2 (MacPro Pro, Processor Core i7)
rails 3.1.0
ruby 1.9.2
mysql 5.5.19, for osx10.6 (i386)

I can install the mysql gem without problems:
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

I can also login and create a database and a dummy table.

But when I want to set up the mysql db using rake 
rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production" --trace
Then I receive the following error:
uninitialized constant Mysql::Error

Is it possible that the MySQL version is wrongly installed? 
I used the "Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit)", but when I run mysql -V then it says "i386". Isn't this the 32 bit version?
The full output is: 
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.19, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

Comment: uninitialized constant indicates that you did not properly add mysql as dependency to your project. how is your gemfile?

Comment: Thanks, phoet, but the Gemfile looks fine. It contains the following line: gem 'mysql'

Comment: so this works in development?

Comment: yes, it worked in development, as the development db is sqlight. But now using the mysql2 gem it works also in production

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `bundle install`? Also rather than the old `mysql` gem, it is recommended to use the `mysql2` gem.

And then when you are inside your project's root directory, run your app using bundler:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

When you use bundle, you don't need to install gems using `gem install ...`, just use `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Behrang, mysql2 finally works. First I had to reinstall everything, as something was corrupt, but now it works.